# why i Can't see .net 4.5 on IIS when trying to Add Web Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

On my machine i have vs2012 (with .net 4.5 )

I want to add a new web site to my iis and i can't define this web site as .net4.5 because i see on the application pool only

```
asp.net v4.0 and 
asp.net v4.0 classic
```

I try execute

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

but nothing happened ( 4.0.30319 is the latest on my machine )

Answer (score 0):

Because here it is CLR 4.0, which is the core of all .NET Framework 4.x. In your case as you have applied .NET 4.5, so it is already 4.5.